# Any ideas, how can the code below produce some costume loops into several parts?

Tags: wordpress, loops, sticky

I'm making a loop that contains a sticky post from Wordpress.
Where in the function code below, generate several posts. I want to divide the existing loop into sections.

The first part that contains the first post and the second post until the fifth post. While the second part contains the rest of the posts in the sticky Wordpress post. So, I can design all posts to have a different look.

this is the code :

```php
// Sticky post
function add_custom_sticky_posts(){
    do_action('add_custom_sticky_posts');
}
function add_sticky_posts(){
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'post__in'            => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
 if ( !empty($sticky) ):
    // has sticky posts
    query_posts($args);
 $stickyPosts = new WP_query();
$stickyPosts->query($args);
    if ( $stickyPosts->have_posts() ):
        $counter = 1;
?>

<!-- Sticky Posts Section -->

<section class="sticky-posts">

<?php
    while ( $stickyPosts->have_posts() ) : $stickyPosts->the_post();

if($counter == 1){
     get_template_part('featured');
}

elseif($counter >= 2 && $counter <= 6 ){ ?>
    <article class="second">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <span><?php the_time('g:i A - l j F Y'); ?></span>
    </article>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<article class="third">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <span><?php the_time('g:i A - l j F Y'); ?></span>
        <span><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></span>
</article>
<?php
}
$counter++;
    endwhile; //end loop for sticky posts
?>
<?php
    endif; //have_posts()
?>

</section> <!-- end .sticky-posts -->
<?php
// RESET THE QUERY
wp_reset_query();
endif; //has sticky posts

//END Custom Query for Sticky Posts only
}
add_action('add_custom_sticky_posts','add_sticky_posts');
```

this is the result of the code :

```html
<section class="sticky-posts">
<article class="firts"></article>
<article class="second"></article>
<article class="second"></article>
<article class="second"></article>
<article class="second"></article>
<article class="second"></article>
<article class="third"></article>
<article class="third"></article>
</section>
```

but, I want the results like this :

```html
<section class="sticky-posts">
<div class="primary">
        <div class="first">
                <article class="firts"></article>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
                <article class="second"></article>
                <article class="second"></article>
                <article class="second"></article>
                <article class="second"></article>
                <article class="second"></article>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="secondary">
        <article class="third"></article>
        <article class="third"></article>
</div>
</section>
```

any ideas on how to make it like that ? thank you very much for all the advice

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). PHP code is not runnable with stack snippets, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: sorry and thank you for the correction. Is my code now in the right format?

Comment: Yes, I think there's nothing more to correct

Comment: Oh, ok. So, do you have any ideas about my question ? I am thinking of making a custom loop of more than 1. But, I still have no idea at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with php, just tried to help make your question easier to answer for others, sorry

Comment: Ok, no worries. Have a good day